# Does it matter who executes a Limit?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-3

There are a lot of different limit possibilities in the game, and I'm wondering if for some of the more generic ones, it matters which characters get assigned to them, and of those, which in particular does the executing.

For example, one of the first Limits you get is Cross Slash, which you have to assign to two characters. Do the stats/gear of the characters it is assigned to matter in terms of how much damage it does? And does it matter which of the two guys it is assigned to I actually trigger it with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stats of all characters involved in a Limit influence the effects of it. For example, two physical attackers with good STR will do better with Cross Slash than two Zodiacs, or a physical attacker and a non-physical attacker. This has to do with the general performance.

However, beyond that, **the person who initiates the Limit is the one whose skills are taken into play**. This is very, very, *very* important to take into consideration. If you have a buffing Limit, then a Prince or Princess using it will heal all your allies if she has the appropriate skill. A Zodiac's skill to increase damage on foes weak to an element will affect it if the Zodiac is the one who uses it. If you use Charge or Ether Charge on a person and then that person performs the Limit, then it will be boosted accordingly if possible.

Thus, proper assignment of Limits will involve picking people whose stats are appropriate, and also picking the one person whose skills will help it most.